# Block Controller Method while already running

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a controller which returns a large json object. If this object does not exist, it will generate and return it afterwards. The generation takes about 5 seconds, and if the client sent the request multiple times, the object gets generated with x-times the children. So my question is: Is there a way to block the second request, until the first one finished, independent who sent the request?

Normally I would do it with a Singleton, but because I am having scoped services, singleton does not work here

Comment: Is session enabled? If so you could put a flag in there.

Comment: I can literally think of 6 different ways of doing this, so it's difficult to know what would be the best, because a lot of requirements aren't mentioned. For example what RubbleFord refers to is per-client, while I automatically assumed that you want it to be at least service-wide. That makes 7. :) E.g. do you need to synchronize between different app instances? But the simplest way (for a single service instance) is obviously just a static field, perhaps handled with `Interlocked.CompareExchange` to make  it atomic.

Comment: @Leaky I was about to write down, that I need it service-wide :'D Well no, I only have one instance, at least for now. Do you have an example for `Interlocked.CompareExchange`?

Comment: IMHO use a `Lazy<Task<...>>` to ensure your code starts exactly once. Multiple requests can then await the same Task.

Comment: Also, just because you need scoped services to build the large object, doesn't mean that the service that builds that object needs to be scoped. You can create your own scope in an `IHostedService` to build the object once on startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you have an example for `Interlocked.CompareExchange`?

Sure. I'm definitely not the most knowledgeable person when it comes to multi-threading stuff, but this is quite simple (as you might know, `Interlocked` has no support for `bool`, so it's customary to represent it with an integral type):

```csharp
    public class QueryStatus
    {
        private static int _flag;

        // Returns false if the query has already started.
        public bool TrySetStarted()
            => Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _flag, 1, 0) == 0;

        public void SetFinished()
            => Interlocked.Exchange(ref _flag, 0);
    }
```

I think it's the safest if you use it like this, with a 'Try' method, which tries to set the value and tells you if it was already set, in an atomic way.

Besides simply adding this (I mean just the field and the methods) to your existing component, you can also use it as a separate component, injected from the IOC container as scoped. Or even injected as a singleton, and then you don't have to use a static field.

Storing state like this should be good for as long as the application is running, but if the hosted application is recycled due to inactivity, it's obviously lost. Though, that won't happen while a request is still processing, and definitely won't happen in 5 seconds.

(And if you wanted to synchronize between app service instances, you could 'quickly' save a flag to the database, in a transaction with proper isolation level set. Or use e.g. Azure Redis Cache.)

#### Example solution

As Kit noted, rightly so, I didn't provide a full solution above.

So, a crude implementation could go like this:

```csharp
public class SomeQueryService : ISomeQueryService
{
    private static int _hasStartedFlag;

    private static bool TrySetStarted()
        => Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _hasStartedFlag, 1, 0) == 0;

    private static void SetFinished()
        => Interlocked.Exchange(ref _hasStartedFlag, 0);

    public async Task<(bool couldExecute, object result)> TryExecute()
    {
        if (!TrySetStarted())
            return (couldExecute: false, result: null);

        // Safely execute long query.

        SetFinished();
        return (couldExecute: true, result: result);
    }
}

// In the controller, obviously
[HttpGet()]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoLongQuery([FromServices] ISomeQueryService someQueryService)
{
    var (couldExecute, result) = await someQueryService.TryExecute();

    if (!couldExecute)
    {
        return new ObjectResult(new ProblemDetails
        {
            Status = StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable,
            Title = "Another request has already started. Try again later.",
            Type = "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.4"
        })
        { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable };
    }

    return Ok(result);
}
```

Of course possibly you'd want to extract the 'blocking' logic from the controller action into somewhere else, for example an action filter. In that case the flag should also go into a separate component that could be shared between the query service and the filter.

#### General use action filter

I felt bad about my inelegant solution above, and I realized that this problem can be generalized into basically a connection number limiter on an endpoint.

I wrote this small action filter that can be applied to any endpoint (multiple endpoints), and it accepts the number of allowed connections:

```csharp
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ConcurrencyLimiterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly int _allowedConnections;
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> _connections = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();

    public ConcurrencyLimiterAttribute(int allowedConnections = 1)
        => _allowedConnections = allowedConnections;

    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var key = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;

        if (_connections.AddOrUpdate(key, 1, (k, v) => ++v) > _allowedConnections)
        {
            Close(withError: true);
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            await next();
        }
        finally
        {
            Close();
        }

        void Close(bool withError = false)
        {
            if (withError)
            {
                context.Result = new ObjectResult(new ProblemDetails
                {
                    Status = StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable,
                    Title = $"Maximum {_allowedConnections} simultaneous connections are allowed. Try again later.",
                    Type = "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.4"
                })
                { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable };
            }

            _connections.AddOrUpdate(key, 0, (k, v) => --v);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the actual question? This answers a question in the comments.

Comment: @Kit I can't do much better without having some code samples that provide a context for placing the solution. Also, the OP doesn't seem inexperienced, so I'm not even sure if further help is needed. But if you have some ideas, I'd be happy to improve the answer.

Comment: This answer helps definitly, especially because the question was about "how can I do this". I am trying to implement a helper class which I can inject and use, but need some time before I can accept this answer

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin added an example solution meanwhile. Not sure if helpful, but maybe. :)

Comment: Very good example. I implemented a loop which pauses for a second as long as the generator is running. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin great, I'm happy it helped. I also added a generalized action filter solution to the end of the answer; maybe that one will be useful for someone as well.

Comment: @Leaky Yes that also helps, thanks. Just a small question though this issue is already solved: Is there a way to have a List<int> with Interlocked? So all IDs which are generated right now are stored inside the List, and if a request wants to run the function with an id which is generating right now, it waits until the generation is finished?  This way I will not block other requests if the id is already generated

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin I'm not sure how does your use of the List look like, but if you're using it to store operation IDs and their associated 'is it running' flag, then you can easily use a `ConcurrentDictionary` for that the exact same way I'm using it in the filter example (key will be int). The problem with the List, as far as I understand, is that `Add()` cannot be atomic, since a lot of things might happen in the background. Enumeration also can't be atomic. On the other hand, you can use an array with InterLocked, e.g. `InterLocked.CompareExchange(ref arr[indx], ...)`.

Comment: I can only hope I'm not giving you bullshit advice, because I'm legit pretty bad at multi-threading.  But of course you can always just use locks instead of InterLocked, if locking is not a problem performance-wise. Actually ConcurrentDictionary uses locks too in the background, as far as I understand.

Comment: I managed to solve it via a `ConcurrentBag<int>`. When the model with ID 1 is being generated, it adds the number 1 to the bag and other threads are waiting until the bag doesn't contain 1. Thanks again for you help :)

Answer (score 1):

Warning: this is very oppinionated and maybe not suitable for Stack Overflow, but here it is anyway

Although I'll provide no code... when things take a while to generate, you don't usually spend that time directly in controller code, but do something like "start a background task to generate the result, and provide a "task id", which can be queried on another different call).

So, my preferred course of action for this would be having two different controller actions:

- `Generate`, which creates the background job, assigns it some id, and returns the id
- `GetResult`, to which you pass the task id, and returns either different error codes for "job id doesn't exist", "job id isn't finished", or a 200 with the result.

This way, your clients will need to call both, however, in `Generate`, you can check if the job is already being created and return an existing job id.

This of course moves the need to "retry and check" to your client: in exchange, you don't leave the connection to the server opened during those 5 seconds (which could potentially be multiplied by a number of clients) and return fast.

Otherwise, if you don't care about having your clients wait for a response during those 5 seconds, you could do a simple:

```
if(resultDoesntExist) {
   resultDoesntExist = false; // You can use locks for the boolean setters or Interlocked instead of just setting a member
   resultIsBeingGenerated = true;
   generateResult(); // <-- this is what takes 5 seconds
   resultIsBeingGenerated = false;
}
while(resultIsBeingGenerated) { await Task.Delay(10); } // <-- other clients will wait here
var result = getResult(); // <-- this should be fast once the result is already created
return result;
```

*note:* those booleans and the actual loop could be on the controller, or on the service, or wherever you see fit: just be wary of making them thread-safe in however method you see appropriate

So you basically make other clients wait till the first one generates the result, with "almost" no CPU load on the server... however with a connection open and a thread from the threadpool used, so I just **DO NOT** recommend this :-)

PS: @Leaky solution above is also good, but it also shifts the responsability to retry to the client, and if you are going to do that, I'd probably go directly with a "background job id", instead of having the first (the one that generates the result) one take 5 seconds. IMO, if it can be avoided, no API action should ever take 5 seconds to return :-)

Comment: Very good suggestion, never thought of returning a Task Id if the generator is running. This is not a direkt answer to my question, because this does not prevent the generator to run twice simulatanously, but it makes my code way better on top. Thanks a lot!